# Context of trailing lambda

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

Below you can see a trailing lambda syntax:

```
  runApplication</*... */>(/*... */) {
    setBannerMode(/*... */)
  }
```

I understand the idea that we can pass a lambda outside the parens as a last argument. But what does the code above actually do? `setBannerMode` is a method that is going to override the one in the parent class, isn't it? If yes, what class is the parent one? Is there some `this` context between the braces of the trailing lambda? In general, what's happening there?

the code is from [here](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/)

Comment: `setBannerMode` is just called on `this` which is instance of SpringApplication, passed by the runApplication function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> setBannerMode is a method that is being overriden, isn't it?

No. What you are doing is passing a lambda to `runApplication()` that has a `this` [implicit receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver) .

[Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/bd179393eafb53fa52477b295745237d93d62c77/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/kotlin/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplicationExtensions.kt#L41) is the definition ([Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/boot-features-kotlin.html#boot-features-kotlin-api-runapplication)):

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> runApplication(vararg args: String, init: SpringApplication.() -> Unit): ConfigurableApplicationContext =
        SpringApplication(T::class.java).apply(init).run(*args)
```

The `init: SpringApplication.() -> Unit` here is the definition of the lambda with implicit receiver. It means that inside the lambda, `this` will be a `SpringApplication`.

To break it down:

1. `SpringApplication(T::class.java)` - create a new spring application. `T` is calculated from the calling context by the Kotlin compiler (that's what `reified T` means).
2. `apply(init)`. Calls your lambda (`init`), with the `SpringApplication` as the receiver ([Kotlin docs for apply](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#apply)).
3. Call the `SpringApplication`'s `run()` function with the varargs arguments. This function returns a `ConfigurableApplicationContext`.

So, you are calling the `setBannerMode()` method of the instantiated `SpringApplication` object.

Comment: Perfect explanation, thank you! Kotlin has so much implicitness that makes things cryptic for newbies like me.